# Custom Primary Key related entity ID property in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've created a class:

```
public class Client
{
    public long AccountNumber {get;set;}
    // ...
}
```

And I'm using non default (Id) primary key:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasKey(x => x.AccountNumber);
```

And I've got an entity that is in a relationship with `Client`

```
public class Something
{
    public Client Client {get;set;}
}
```

and I'd like to add property that contains Foreign Key value - `ClientAccountNumber`

With the default PK (`Id`, f.e. `Client.Id`) this works out-of-box:

```
public class Client 
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
}

public class Something
{
    public Client Client {get;set;}
    public long ClientId {get;set;}
}
```

With custom PK this doesn't work:

```
public class Something
{
    public Client Client {get;set;}
    public long ClientAccountNumber {get;set;} // some kind of convention? 
                                               //or explicit configuration?
}
```

What should be the name of the property, so EF can figure out that this is simply the FK?
Is there some kind of naming convention?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not", please try to find a more meaningful title for your question!

Comment: Hi Andreas, title contains names of the technologies that I'm using and gives a brief description (based on keywords) about the question itself. Honestly, I can't see why this title is inappropriate

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): *Write a title that summarizes the specific problem*. Your title is just a sequence of terms, and to be honest (but not rude): Questions as titles tend to work better as an introduction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mapping for the foreign key relationship just as you did for the PK.

It is not immediately clear what kind of relationship you want but assuming many to one:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Something>()
.HasRequired(x => x.Client)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(x => x.ClientId);
```